# Gaussian Random Variables Expectation and variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $Z$ be a standard Normal random variable. Let $F$ be a continuous random variable such that

$$g_{F|Z}(f|z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp \left(-\frac{(f+2z)^2}{2}\right).$$

What is $\mathbb E[F|Z=z]$  (as a function of $z$)?

---

I tried to find it by treating $z$ as a constant and used the Normal mean $\mathbb E[F \mid z] = -2\cdot z$.

And then what is $\mathbb E[F]$? What is $\mathrm{COV}(F,Z)$?
I can’t find the variance.

The expectation of the product is $\mathbb E[FZ] = \mathbb E[Z\cdot \mathbb E[F \mid Z]]$

But I can’t find the values.

The conditional PDF of $Z$ given $F=f$ is of the form

$$\alpha(f) e^{−\mathrm{quadratic}(z,f)}$$

By examining the coefficients of the quadratic function in the exponent, can one find $\mathbb E[Z \mid F=f]$ and $\mathbb{V}(Z \mid F=f)$?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Comment: Can you tell me specifics about what’s wrong ?

Comment: use mathjax and include your attempt.

Comment: I did use it and now I included my attemp to solve it .

Comment: The expected value should be $\color{red}-2z$

Comment: @callculus thanks alot man

Comment: @MohamedNabil You´re welcome.